# Constant Length of \underline

Tags: underline

My question is incorporated in the code/output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The underline \underline{\qquad} (\verb+\underline{\qquad}+) is the length of
the underline that I would like to have no matter the contents of the
\verb+\underline+ argument. The length of the contents is always shorter than
2em (a \verb+\qquad+).

Example: I would like, say, `$1$' and `$11$' to be placed at the middle of an
\underline{\qquad} (\verb+\underline{\qquad}+).\\[\baselineskip]
How do I achieve that?

\end{document}
```

[image: question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `\funderline` will have a fixed minimum width of `\qquad`, but will grow if the length of the word demands it.  I accomplish it by underlining a superimposed stack of the argument `#1` and a `\qquad`, with center alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\funderline[1]{\underline{\stackengine{0pt}{\qquad}{#1}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
This is \funderline{a} \funderline{test} of an \funderline{extremely} long underline.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I misunderstood the question, and the intent is to have the underline **always** be 2em length, even if the word is longer, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\funderline[1]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\underline{\qquad\vphantom{#1}}}{#1}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
This is \funderline{a} \funderline{test} of an \funderline{extremely} long underline.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I really didn't think of the latter possibility since the contants that I'm working with always is shorter than a `\qquad`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Change the `c` to an `r` for right alignment or to an `l` for left alignment.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out myself. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

When using `\makebox`, `\width` refers to the natural width of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\wideunderline}[2][2em]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

This is short \wideunderline{11} and
\wideunderline{this is long}.

You can specify a longer one:
\wideunderline[6em]{11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first optional argument to `\makebox` should be a dimension; TeX expands token when looking for it and it will already have set `\width` to the natural width of the text in the mandatory argument. Since the token list starts with `\ifdim`, TeX does the comparison and follows either the true branch or the false branch. In the “true” case, that is when `#1` (which stands for the optional argument to `\wideunderline` or the default value `2em` if missing) is larger than `\width`, `\width` is returned, otherwise `#1` is returned.

Comment: Hi Enrico. Can you elaborate a bit on what `\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi` does?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Added

Comment: golly, i do find the different vertical positioning of underlined strings with or without descenders discombobulating!  there's got to be a reasonable way to make them more uniform.  it might be to ignore the descenders and overprint.  have you seen any published recommendations about this?

Comment: @barbarabeeton There are several threads on the site about it. I'd not go too much into the details; I guess the OP can do it by himself. Hint: `\smash[b]{...}` the argument (requires `amsmath`).

Answer (score 3):

Here you are. I added a variant, based on `eqparbox` which allows all `\ulmakebox` sharing the same tag (default ULB) to have the same underlining width, with a minimum of 2em:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox, ulem}
\newcommand\ulmakebox[2][ULB]{\eqsetminwidth{#1}{2em}\underline{\eqmakebox[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

The underline \underline{\qquad} (\verb+\underline{\qquad}+) is the length of the underline that I would like to have no matter the contents of the \verb+\underline+ argument. The length of the contents is always shorter than 2em (a \verb+\qquad+).

Example: I would like, say, `$1$' and `$11$' to be placed at the middle of an \underline{\qquad} (\verb+\underline{\qquad}+).\\[\baselineskip]
How do I achieve that?
\underline{\makebox[2em]{$1$}}\quad\underline{\makebox[2em]{$11$}}\bigskip

\ulmakebox{I would like} \ulmakebox{$ 1 $} and \ulmakebox{$ 11 $} to be placed at the middle of an \verb|\underline|

\end{document}
```

[image]